# can not implement 3d bar highchart in vuejs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vuejs3

I'm using **Highcharts** library to create some **3d** bar chart

I've used Highcharts document example to create base 3d bar chart (link [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-column-interactive) )

But , it draw just a **simple** chart like this

[image]

I've copied all options from document

I think there is something with importing 3d modules

and this is my code in [code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/high-chart-vue-3-3d-column-2feiv5?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import and initialize the 3d module.

```
import highchart from "highcharts";
import highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";

highcharts3d(highchart);
```

Also, I recommend you use the officially supported wrapper for Highcharts in Vue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tristan-wvup-wvup03

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm